# Is it possible to customize the \textcite command in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, citing

Today i am constructing a project template in latex. So far i have succeeded in building up the biblatex environment (with some help from some guys of this forum as well ^^). Now i have moved on to the citations.

Now, when i use the `\textcite{key}` command, in the document it displays as `Author1 et al. [refNumber]`.

The unfortunate thing is, that i have some guidelines for my project, and the display convention will be:

```
It has been previously shown that biblatex is superior to bibtex (cf. Author1 et al. [refNumber]).
```

As for now, what i am typing is the following `(cf. \textcite{key})`.

Now, my question is: Is there a way to customize the \textcite command in such a way that, when typing `textcite{key}`, that it directly generates my desired format?

Best regards

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is, to wrap the `textcite`-command in your own command. You could define:

```
\newcommand{\cfcite}[2][]{(\textcite[cf.][#1]{#2})}
```

and use it like:

```
It has been previously shown that biblatex is superior to bibtex \cfcite{key}.
It has been previously shown that biblatex is superior to bibtex \cfcite[50]{key}.
```

Maybe you have to put the `cf.` in front of the `\textcite`, that depends of your biblatex-style:

```
\newcommand{\cfcite}[2][]{(cf.~\textcite[#1]{#2})}
```

Comment: The \newcommand way is what i have tried before, but then it isn't possible to do someting like `\cfcite[p. 56]{key}` to get something like `(cf. Author1 et. al, p. 56)`.

As for the \textcite[cf.]{key} version, unfortunately it puts the cf. before the refNumber, i.e. `Author1 [refNumber, cf.]`.

Comment: I've updated my answer. The problem with your `cf.` is, that the biblatex-commands always look like `\citecommand[prenote][postnote]{key}`. That means, if you want to set a prenote, you always **have** to set a postnote, but you can set an empty string fortunately `[]`.